# How to do connection pooling in jboss 5 in xml file

Tags: jboss5.x

I need to add connection pooling in jboss 5 but I don't know to make the changes. I find all configuration related to jboss6. Can any one help me step by step.

Comment: You will need to put a xxx-ds.xml file in the /deploy folder that will define your connection and pool parameters. Which database are you using?

Comment: Thanks microsoft sql server

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Put your MS SQL JDBC Driver in your /lib directory, for sqlserver it is called `sqljdbc.jar`

Step 2. Put a datasource definition file in deploy directory. Call it `ms-sql-ds.xml` or something ending in `-ds.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <datasources>
    <local-tx-datasource>
      <jndi-name>DefaultDS</jndi-name>
      <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=pubs</connection-url>
      <driver-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver-class>
      <user-name>sa</user-name>
      <password>jboss</password>
      <pool>  
           <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>  
           <max-pool-size>50</max-pool-size>  
           <prefill>false</prefill>  
           <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>  
           <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>  
      </pool>
      <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT 1 FROM sysobjects</check-valid-connection-sql>
      <metadata>
         <type-mapping>MS SQLSERVER2008</type-mapping>
      </metadata>
    </local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>
```

Note: I don't have a SQL Server instance to test this with but if it is correct you will see some configuration messages in the log file and you can also verify the datasource connectivity through the JBoss conole. My answer is based on information here -> https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HowToSetADatasourceConnectionToMSSQLServer